# Checking for a nested, templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

I'm trying to build a trait that checks for the existence of a nested, templated class. This is my take for checking whether a class `O` has a nested class `inner` with template parameter `T`:

```c++
template <typename O, typename T> struct has_inner {
    static const bool value = std::is_class<typename O::template inner<T> >::value;
};
```

However, this does not work properly. Given two example classes `dummy` and `ok`

```c++
struct dummy {};
struct ok {
    template <typename T>
    struct inner {
    };
};
```

The check on `ok`

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_inner<ok, float>::value << std::endl;
```

will work, whereas the check on `dummy`

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_inner<dummy, int>::value << std::endl;
```

will fail to compile on clang 3.2 with the error

```
error: 'inner' following the 'template' keyword does not refer to a template
    static const bool value = std::is_class<typename O::template inner<T> >::value;
                                                                 ^~~~~
note: in instantiation of template class 'has_inner<dummy, int>' requested here
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_inner<dummy, int>::value << std::endl;
```

It appears that the compiler tries to actually form that templated expression prior to passing it on to `std::is_class`. Consequently I see two solutions:

1. Tell the compiler to delay the template expansion, or
2. Use a different approach altogether.

However, I don't know how to perform either, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### THE PROBLEM

You normally implement traits like this using, and relying on, [*SFINAE*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), something which your implementation doesn't take advantage of.

As stated the compiler will try to instantiate `typename O::template inner<T>`, no matter if it's possible or not; and if it isn't possible the compiler will throw an error diagnostic in your face.

What you need to do is a conditional check to see if `T` actually has a *template-class* inside it, without instantiating it if it hasn't.

---

#### THE SOLUTION - SFINAE TO THE RESCUE!

An implementation might look like the below snippet, an explanation will follow.

```
namespace impl {
  template<class T, class... Args>
  struct has_inner {
    template<class U, typename = typename U::template inner<Args...>> // (A)
    static std::true_type  test (int);

    template<class U>
    static std::false_type test (...);                                // (B)

    using result_type = decltype (test<T> (0));                       // (C)
  };
}

template<class... Ts>
using has_inner = typename impl::has_inner<Ts...>::result_type;
```

> <sup>**Note**: by using `decltype(test<T>(0))` we will have either *std::true_type*, or *std::false_type* which are both the standard behavior when dealing with results from *type-traits*.</sup>

---

The rules of *SFINAE* states that if a function template would yield an invalid function declaration upon instantiation, it is as if this function didn't exist, the compiler will try searching for another match, instead of giving up.

This is what happens at (C), we try to call (A) but if that fails (ie. an invalid expression is yield inside `template<class U, typename ...>`  we will end up calling (B).

(B) isn't as good match as a successful instantiation of (A), but if (A) can't be instantiated.. (B) will do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a trait class and SFINAE, something like this:

```
template<class A, typename B>
struct has_inner
{
private:
    template<class T, typename U>
    static std::true_type has(typename T::template inner<U>*);

    template<class, typename>
    static std::false_type has(...);
public:
    static constexpr auto value = decltype(has<A, B>(nullptr))::value;
};
```

Now you can use it with correct results:

```
static_assert(has_inner<ok, float>::value, "ok does not have inner");    // OK
static_assert(has_inner<dummy, float>::value, "dummy does not have inner"); // ERROR
```